# why swift use a struct as dictionary key instead of a string here?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, uiimagepickercontroller

Why `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey` type is struct not a string ,what is the benefit to use struct as a dictionary key instead of string?

```
public struct InfoKey : Hashable, Equatable, RawRepresentable {

    public init(rawValue: String)
}
}
extension UIImagePickerController.InfoKey {


public static let mediaType: UIImagePickerController.InfoKey

public static let originalImage: UIImagePickerController.InfoKey // a UIImage

public static let editedImage: UIImagePickerController.InfoKey // a UIImage

public static let cropRect: UIImagePickerController.InfoKey // an NSValue (CGRect)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, the benefit is the ability to check key values during compilation. This way, you won't be able to pass a `String` directly and if you do, you have to manually wrap it into a `InfoKey` structure, making your intention clear.

Most of the times you should be using one of the predefined constants.

An `enum` would be a better solution but probably that would break some existing code  (and cannot be really enforced in Objective-C).

If Apple engineers were creating a new API today, they wouldn't probably even use a dictionary but they would use a custom object to pass the values to the delegate method.

Comment: Some additional info: The type is defined as `typedef NSString * UIImagePickerControllerInfoKey NS_TYPED_ENUM;` in the Objective-C header, and `NS_TYPED_ENUM` is what makes it a struct in Swift: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/objective-c_and_c_code_customization/grouping_related_objective-c_constants.