# iOS - Why the apple using structure for Notification name instead of String Constants?

Tags: ios, swift, string

I noticed that the apple is using `struct` to define `Notification` names. I believe `String` constants are straight forward to use and no need to initialize another `struct` and use `rawValue`.

So I'm eager to know the reason behind using `struct` instead of `String` directly.

**Note: I found an answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56147956/why-swift-use-a-struct-as-dictionary-key-instead-of-a-string-here). But I'm not clear with that answer.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56147956/why-swift-use-a-struct-as-dictionary-key-instead-of-a-string-here) is the same question

Comment: Above link might have answers, but I'm not clear with answers in another link. So I created a new question here.

Comment: In what way are you "not clear"? Can you explain why that answer isn't satisfactory.

Comment: That answer is clearly focusing on Dictionary Key, which can be either `Number` or `String` as key. But my question here is clearly says that the Notification name should be a `String` value, but why do we need an extra `struct`(Notification.Name) to initialize with String as rawValue?. Anyways if you guys still feel this question as duplicate, I can remove this and ask in apple developer forum.